# Shared variable for multiple router methods in express

Tags: node.js, express

Lets assume user hits url domain/rest/music/?page=2

Then in backend, I have express router for rest:

```
app.use('/rest', restRouter);
```

where rest router is something like that

```
var express = require('express');
var restRouter = express.Router();
```

To the question. If my router has following methods:

```
restRouter.get('*', createRequestInstance);
restRouter.get('*', findUser);
restRouter.get('/music/*', getMusicList);
```

I want to create some object variable that will flow thru resolving algorithm and harvest data during the process. But if I create this object in `createRequestInstance`, I dont know how could I pass it to `findUser` or `getMusicList`. **I would prefer to not modify** `req` **and** `res` **objects or use express-native technique**. I want to prepare everything first and then build response.

I see following problems

1. I cant define variable outside of function definition, because it would be shared across all requests. And I want to have one unique object for each request.
2. Functions only accepts `req`, `res`, `next` params. And I dont see the way how to augment it even with bind.
3. I cant call next function manualy, because it is being called via `next`, so I cant pass additional parameters inside.

Comment: The express way is to have a private variable, `req._data = {}`, and build on that as the request passes through the stack of middlewares. Can you tell me why are you against modifying the `req` ?

Comment: Sure, if you have more authors, more routers and you would like to separate data for each router/method so it cant be accidentally damaged. I would say it might be common practise you can add some params/obj for next method. Im sure someone had to think about this before, for example when he compared `async` and `express`

Comment: Umm..Just so you know that's exactly what `res.locals` does. It makes them  kind of global for all routers / middlewares/ methods that have access to `res` and not to mention all the views, if any. For having one unique object for each request, have a `count` on `app/server.js` or its equivalent . Then all your routes/middlewares/methods having access to `count` can create an unique object  for each request . I believe, you should be also do the same with `res.locals`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common method is to use [`res.locals`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.locals), which is intended for this sort of thing.

Comment: Great! I had to miss it when I was going thru the documentation :)